# How to get the first day of a particular year in informix?

Tags: sql, informix, dbeaver

I'm trying to return the 1st day of a particular year in Informix using MDY function.

The function returns the expected value for current date. However, it's not working as expected if I gave any other year in parameters

[image]

My expected result is 2010-01-01. I'm using DBeaver to connect to the Informix database.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=functions-mdy-function) third parameter is 4-digit year, so please try MDY(1, 1, 2010).

Comment: The YEAR function expects a DATE argument. In Informix, a DATE value is a count of the days since 1899-12-31, so day 1 is 1900-01-01.  The number 2010 represents 1905-07-03.  Hence, the result you get is what you asked for — you didn't ask for what you wanted.  As already explained, simply provide the year number as the third argument to MDY.  Although you will rarely need such dates, if you use `MDY(1, 1, 1)`, the date value corresponds to 0001-01-01 (first of January, year 1). Be aware that Informix uses the so-called "proleptic Gregorian calendar"; it uses the modern rules for leap years.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the year function use the below query to get the expected output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TODAY,
  MDY(1, 1, YEAR(TODAY)),
  MDY(1, 1, 2010)
FROM sales_product;
```